# R MatchIt: Using ratio and caliper arguments seems to force replace=T

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I'm using the MatchIt package in R to perform propensity score matching. Matching method is nearest neighbour and distance measure is glm. When I leave ratio and caliper set to the defaults or if I enter a non default value for just one of them, I get the distribution of weights that I expect without replacement, i.e. all 0 or 1. However, when I set both to non default values I get some weights higher than 1 and some between 0 and 1, which is a distribution I associate with replacement.

Am I misunderstanding the difference between sampling with and without replacement, or is this a case that overrides the replace=F argument? I have read the package documentation but it is very possible that I missed or misunderstood the section that explains this. If so, feel free to simply direct me to the relevant section!

A (hopefully) reproducible example:

```
set.seed(42)
DF<-data.frame(Group=factor(c(rep("Treatment",40),rep("Control",360))),
               mVar1=factor(c(sample(LETTERS[c(1,1,1,2)],40,replace=T),sample(LETTERS[c(1,2)],360,replace=T))),
               mVar2=factor(c(sample(LETTERS[c(3,3,4,4,4,5)],40,replace=T),sample(LETTERS[c(3,4,5)],360,replace=T))),
               mVar3=c(rpois(40,3),rpois(360,1)))
str(DF)

(m1<-matchit(Group~mVar1+mVar2+mVar3,data=DF,method="nearest",distance="glm",ratio=3,replace=F))
plot(m1,type="jitter",interactive=FALSE)
hist(m1$weights)

(m2<-matchit(Group~mVar1+mVar2+mVar3,data=DF,method="nearest",distance="glm",caliper=0.1,replace=F))
plot(m2,type="jitter",interactive=FALSE)
hist(m2$weights)

(m3<-matchit(Group~mVar1+mVar2+mVar3,data=DF,method="nearest",distance="glm",ratio=3,caliper=0.1,replace=F))
plot(m3,"jitter",interactive=FALSE)
hist(m3$weights)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching weights are computed using the formula described at `?matchit`. This formula is used when matching *without* replacement, as you are doing. The formula is as follows:

> Each unit is assigned to a subclass, which represents the pair they
> are a part of (in the case of k:1 matching) or the stratum they belong
> to (in the case of exact matching, coarsened exact matching, full
> matching, or subclassification). The formula for computing the weights
> depends on the argument supplied to estimand. A new stratum
> "propensity score" (p) is computed as the proportion of units in each
> stratum that are in the treated group, and all units in that stratum
> are assigned that propensity score. Weights are then computed using
> the standard formulas for inverse probability weights: for the ATT,
> weights are 1 for the treated units and p/(1-p) for the control units;
> for the ATC, weights are (1-p)/p for the treated units and 1 for the
> control units; for the ATE, weights are 1/p for the treated units and
> 1/(1-p) for the control units.
>
> ...
>
> In each treatment group, weights are divided by the mean of the
> nonzero weights in that treatment group to make the weights sum to the
> number of units in that treatment group.

When using a constant matching ratio (e.g., every treated unit gets 1 match or every treated unit gets 3 matches), the weights will be constant for all control units. Otherwise, the weights will vary for control units. What you are seeing is the weight varying for control units. It happens to be that this also can occur with matching with replacement, but it can also occur when variable-ratio matching or full matching, both of which without replacement.

To see if you are actually matching with replacement, run `table(table(m3$match.matrix))`. `table(m3$match.matrix)` tells you how many times each control unit is used as a match, and running `table()` on that output tells you how many times a control unit is used each number of times. You will see that each control unit is used only once, so there will be only one entry in the output of `table(table())`, indicating matching is being done without replacement.

Comment: Thank you @Noah. That's incredibly helpful!